# How to center reduced reCaptcha? HTML CSS

Tags: css, center, recaptcha, captcha

How can I center horizontally reCaptcha box? Why is it so hard to do? 
HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">          
   <label>Email</label>
   <input class="input" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email" required>                 
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="here is key"></div>               
</form>
```

I made it smaller by this CSS code:

```
.g-recaptcha{
transform:scale(0.2);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.2);
transform-origin:0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just add padding-left: 25%; can be in pixels. margin set auto;
Or text-align center